# before_tag(context, tag) not working in django-behave

Tags: django

i am not able to see the before_tag(context, tag) function work ! can't seem to find the reason. Has anyone used this . the documentation doesn't give any examples of any of the environment functions, rest of them work fine, but before_tag  isn't. I have the following:

```
def before_tag(context, tag):
    print '-*****-before TAG--****'
    if tag == 'given':
        print '---tag found---'
```

in my environment.py
and it doesn't print...

Comment: what is this supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps none of the scenarios in your feature files are tagged with a tag, or not tagged with the tags you are providing as arguments to the `behave` command.